# R Cut Function and Indicator Variable

Tags: r, cut

I am learning r and reading a book that has the below code, which is creating a indicator variable of 0 or 1 for the variable don$TGiving.  I understand the first part of the code but do not understand how to read `c(-1,0.5,10000000),labels=FALSE)-1` and how this make  a 0 or 1 value.  Basically if don$TGiving is more than 0 it returns a 1 otherwise it is a 0 in the new variable don$TGivingIND.

```
don$TGivingIND=cut(don$TGiving,c(-1,0.5,10000000),labels=FALSE)-1
```

How exactly do you read this code?

Is there a more intuitive way to get the same result?

Thank you.

Comment: cut converts to factors which count from 1, not 0, so for two levels you would get 1s and 2s; subtracting 1 would give 0s and 1s. This seems intuitive to me, but you could use `ifelse(condition, 1, 0)`, i.e., 1 if condition is true, 0 otherwise. You could also use `findInterval`

Comment: I can see why you're confused. That is just plain terrible code that obscures from the intended result. The examples given by @rawr are much cleaner.

Comment: Thank you.  This worked much better for me:   'don$TGivingIND=ifelse(don$TGiving>0,1,0)' and is much more intuitive for my mind.:)

Comment: If there's not going to be an answer then you should delete the question, rather than leaving it "unanswered".

Comment: @rawr - it's your answer for the taking mate.